# Default iptables rules location centos 7

Tags: iptables

Seems like after rebooting the servers iptables rules gets loaded. But I can't find its location to delete the rules. There's no /etc/sysconfig/iptables as mentioned in /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config

```
[root@hostname ~]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centos 7 uses firewalld to manage rules. There are two directories which store configuration files:

- `/usr/lib/firewalld` stores default presets with definitions of zones and rules.
- `/etc/firewalld` stores user-customized rules that override the default rule set.

A good starting point to dive into firewalld is [the red hat portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls).